# F# Odata service type provider through http proxy

Tags: .net, proxy, f#, type-providers

I want to use odata type provider but it causes next error while compiling: `(407) proxy authentication required`.
There are no errors at design time. Does anybody know how to set the proxy in type provider?
Sample code:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders
type db = ODataService<"http://ebayodata.cloudapp.net/">
[<EntryPoint>]
     let main argv=
           let eBay = db.GetDataContext()
           0
```

Comment: Maybe this post provides some clues: http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2009/07/11/f-downloading-a-file-from-behind-a-proxy/

Comment: What happens if you specify credentials? `Ebay.Credentials <- System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "pass", "domain")`

Comment: Sorry, that was stupid, you said it was during compile-time, not run-time.

Answer (score 2):

This [blog posting](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2012/09/21/the-f-3-0-freebase-type-provider-sample-integrating-internet-scale-data-sources-into-a-strongly-typed-language.aspx) mentions some sample code which may cover proxies.

> The Freebase type provider can be used with .NET 3.5, .NET 4.0, .NET
>   4.5, Silverlight and Portable programming. A proxy may be needed in some cases. The projects in Tests\ProjectsUsingTypeProvider.sln show
>   some sample libraries for these different cases.

You might wish to look at [this file](http://fsharp3sample.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/18045#315092) specifically as well.

Comment: They mean proxy as design pattern. But I mean proxy as http web proxy

Comment: No they mean proxy as in "http web proxy".  Look at the file which I just added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify a default web proxy as follows:

```
open System.Net // for WebProxy etc.
open Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders

// put here actual proxy address
let proxy = new WebProxy("http://192.168.1.1:3128") :> IWebProxy
// put here your credentials if needed
proxy.Credentials <- NetworkCredential("proxy_user", "password")
// set up a default proxy
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy <- proxy

// here the default proxy will be used
type db = ODataService<"http://ebayodata.cloudapp.net/">
```

Or you can try to use a proxy which was specified in IE as follows:

```
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy <- WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy()
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.Credentials <- CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials
```

If you have an error while compiling then this is probably because of F# compiler (Fsc.exe) can't connect to the proxy server. You can fix this by modifying `Fsc.exe.config`, just add the following text under the `configuration` section:

```
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" />    
  </system.net>
```